# jQuery UI Sortable - serialize multiple columns

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, serialization

I have a little script which allows me to use jQuery to sort div tags nicely between 3 columns.  The jQuery can be seen below:

```
$(".column").sortable(
 { connectWith: '.column' },
 { update: function(event, ui) { alert($(this).sortable('serialize')) }
});
```

If I move an item from column 1 to column 2, it will display 2 alerts, showing the serialized data for the 2 affected columns.  The problem is, I need to know the column ids too, so I can eventually save the data into a database.  Right now, if it is possible to just display the column id in an alert but, that will be enough for me to continue.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".column").sortable(
  { connectWith: '.column' }, { update: function(event, ui) {
     alert($(this).sortable('serialize'));
     alert($(this).parents('.column').attr(id));
  }
});
```

I think that should work. Finding the parent column of the div you've moved, and then gettings it's id attribute.

Comment: `this.id` gets the column Id, no need for parents, attr etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just solved this with a very very dirty trick. Like to share it with you, maybe it helps.

```
<div class="column" >
  <div class="portlet" id="portlet_1_name">
     <div class="portlet-header">Title1</div>
     <div class="portlet-content">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="portlet" id="portlet_2_name">
     <div class="portlet-header">Title2</div>
     <div class="portlet-content">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- for debug -->
<div id="serial"></div>
```

etc...

```
var out = "";

$('.portlet').each(function(index) {
   out += $(this).attr('id') + ',';
});

$("#serial").html(out);
// or alert(out) if you like
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working using the "closest" method:

{ update: function(event, ui) { 
alert($(this).closest("div").attr("id")); 
alert($(this).sortable('serialize'))
}

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a good answer to this and none of the ones on here really were exactly what I wanted, so I'll share the way I did it:

```
$('ul.playerList').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); // get element id
    window[id] = $(this).sortable("serialize",{key:id}); // make global var w/ data
});

// you could make this more dynamic if you have a lot of lists
var data = ul_id_1 + "&" + ul_id_2 + "&" + ul_id_3 + "&action=other_vars"; 

$.post(url,data,function(resp) {
    $("#test").html(resp);
});
```